# Does "Nivdak" flour, grains, beans or pasta exist?

Tags: food, product-recommendation, hechsher-certification, bugs, inspection

I know *Bodek*, among other brands sells pre-checked (for bugs, worms, etc.) produce. However, I have not seen any commercially available pre-checked rice, barley (etc. - pretty much any grain that is subject to having worms, bugs, moths, etc.) or flour and pasta. Does it exist? If so, where can I obtain it?

I am not particularly machmir on inspecting grains under an X-ray light, but I hate having moths flying around my cupboard or worms crawling in the rice a few weeks after I buy these things.

Comment: Hey! start a new business.

Comment: @GershonGold - Care to pitch in for the capital ;-)

Comment: @msh210 Went looking for a "bedika" tag when I retagged this question....d'you think we should get that word in the tag description for [tag:inspection]?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, in Eretz Yisroel, there are vacuum packed bags of grains under Badatz supervision. They tend to be slightly more expensive but are "נקי מחשש תולעים". I saw some in stores near the Mir (in the Beit Yisrael neighborhood of Jerusalem), and would guess they're widely available in chareidi neighborhoods.

If your concern is to prevent bugs being born in bought bags, store them in the freezer for at least two days. The colder temperature will kill any bugs or eggs. Personally, i store my flour long-term in the freezer.

Barley can be easily checked and cleaned. Put it in a bowl, fill it with water, and give it a swish. Within a few seconds, bugs, eggs, and other debris (if any) will float to the top. This is hardly an extra step, as bagged barley really needs to washed anyway before use, as it is usually filthy with dirt, little stones, and other things i'd rather not think of.