# Are there kosher bug-inspected brands of rice and flour?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, bugs

I've seen kosher bug-inspected produce such as lettuce and similar greens in kosher markets. But, I have frequently noticed that when I buy rice, barley, and flour and leave these around for a while, ugly bugs and worms start crawling around in these things. I'm unaware of any kosher inspected brands of such grains and flour.

Do these exist? If so, what brand, and would someone know if these are available in specific NY area stores or can be ordered online?

Comment: If you leave any food around long enough it'll start crawling with bugs, even if it is checked

Comment: Considering how quickly bugs and other insects  develop in grain products, perhaps kashrut organizations do not bother checking for bugs . They really can’t certify such products bug-free due to the unlikelihood it would remain that way for any reasonable length of time.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question you asked three years ago (["Does 'Nivdak' flour, grains, beans or pasta exist"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43413/1368))?

Comment: In Israel, they sell vacuum-packed legumes as well as flour in thick plastic bags. These are apparently bug inspected and safe.

Comment: @TamirEvan Indeed, it is. And, I think I hold the record for duping my own questions.